# What is MySQL's SQL dialect called?

Tags: mysql

SQL Server's and Sybase's SQL dialect is called *Transact-SQL*.
Oracle Database's and IBM DB2 accepts and understands *PL/SQL*
PostgreSQL's is called *PL/pgSQL*

What is MySQL's SQL dialect called if it does have a name?

Answer (score 0):

SQL/PSM SQL/Persistent Stored Module (implements SQL/PSM)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL

Comment: A reference would help your answer.

Comment: So MySQL's native procedural dialect is the 'plain' version of SQL/PSM? Is there any reference of this in MySQL documentation?

Comment: No, MySQL does not use a plain version of SQL/PSM... As an example, variables in PSM must not begin by @...